# Установить иконку в TabControl справа

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения, icon

Подскажите пожалуйста, как установить иконку во вкладке `TabControl` с правой стороны?

Вот в левой части вкладки у меня установилась сразу, а справа во вкладке установить никак не получается, устанавливал иконку через `imageList`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В `WinForms` такие вещи довольно нетривиальны. Переходите на `WPF` уже

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/170375/

Answer (score 1):

Берете класс `TabControl` используя наследование порождаете свой класс, и переопределяете в нем:

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    /*Тут рисуете что хотите*/
}
```

Вот, например, люди добавляют крестики и закрытие по нажатию таба:
 [A TabControl with tab page closing capability](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12323/A-TabControl-with-tab-page-closing-capability)